# Searching with spaces in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In a table i have an entry

```
12-345678
123-456-789
123456789
```

In the UI textbox, when someone types: `&nbsp;&nbsp;- (two spaces then one dash).`

output should be:

```
12-345678
```

In the UI textbox, when someone types: `12-`

output should be:

12-345678

In the UI textbox, when someone types: `12`

```
12-345678
123-456-789
123456789
```

My select query to do this is

```
select column1,column2 from table1 where column1 like '%textbox1.text%';
```

textbox1.text-> textbox name of the UI.

Anything before - needs to be returned, for ex:

```
if you type 12-, return output should be 12-345678 alone,
if you type 123-, then the return output should be 123-456-789 alone.
if you type - (only dash, no space on the front , then the return output should be 12-345678 and 123-456-789 .
```

However it fails in few conditions, is there any way i can calculate the space and modify the query directly in sql?

Comment: are you saying two spaces and a dash shoul return 12-345678 because it's the only one where the 3rd char is a dash?

Comment: Anything before - needs to be returned, for ex: if you type 12-, return output should be 12-345678 alone, if you type 123-, then the return output should be 123-456-789 alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly: When there are leading spaces, you need to transform them into `_`. For cases where there are no leading spaces, you can just append `%`.

```
<space><space>-  '__-%'
12-              '12-%'
12               '12%'
123-             '123-%'
```

But this one doesn't fit the pattern, so it's a special case:

```
-                '%-%'
```

I suspect you want a one-line fix, but although you could probably pack it all into a single `iff()`, I would avoid that if possible.

**Edited to add**

C#:

```
string arg = theTextbox.Text;
arg = arg.Replace("'", "''"); // avoid SQL injection attack

arg = arg.Replace(" ", "_"); // space = single character wildcard = '_'

if (arg.StartsWith("-")) // special case
    arg = "%-";

string sqlStatement = string.Format("SELECT column1, column2 " +
             "FROM table1 WHERE column1 like '{0}%', arg);
```

Comment: Thanks, will i be identify the space before - in sql?

Comment: Are you calling SQL from some other language?

Comment: I was supposed to use sql, but I need to do that validation(count the space) in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
"Select column1,column2 From Table1 Where column like " + textbox1.text.Replace(' ','_') + "%"
```

'cept you should use a parameterised query of course.

sql wild card chars are

```
% 0 to n of any character
underscore 1 single character
[xyz] any single character that is x, y or z
```

so in your example it wuld be Like '__-%' 
a space folowed by 2 would be Like '_2%' and pick up all three of your examples as well, as each one is a character followed by "2" followed by someother stuff